# Display two inputs next to each other with label above each html

Tags: html, css, input, label, css-position

I want to do something like this

```
USER         EMAIL
input        input
```

But I can't figure how to get it to display this way. Basically I want each set of label + input field to be a div, but I want the divs to be side by side. Perhaps I'm using the wrong tags because I'm an html noobie ><

Comment: with a little bit css you can do that easily.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`div` is a block level element, that means it will take entire horizontal space by default, inorder to align them side by side, you need to `float` them else you need to use `display: inline-block`

[**Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/FZNWB/)

HTML

```
<div>
    <label>Hello</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
<div>
    <label>Hello</label>
    <input type="text" />
</div>
```

CSS

```
div {
    display: inline-block;
}

div label {
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The float gets it to the right side, but how can I keep the labels above the input fields? When I use a <br> it makes a shifts everything down, not just the elements in that block

Comment: Yeah this can be an option :)

Comment: @user1529956 I contributed a solution, you can refer it :)

Comment: thanks! The inline-block was exactly what I needed. Spent too much time trying to do it with just html tags >.<

Answer (score 2):

if you want to use  tag, then you can achieve your desired result by following code--

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>USER</td>
    <td>EMAIL</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td><input type="text" name="user"></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email"></td>
</tr>
</table>
```

the output is shown here ---
http://jsfiddle.net/hn3U9/